# Getting SpookyJs to work on Nodejs and Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I apologize if this is a basic question, but for the life of me I can't seem to get my Nodejs server to work with Spookyjs.

[Spookyjs](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS) as I understand is a wrapper that allows a user to run casperjs, which is an extension of phantomjs, in a node environment.

Here are my current attempts to get it working: btw this is in CoffeeScript

```
colors = require 'colors'
phantomjs = require 'phantomjs'
Spooky = require 'spooky'

module.exports =
  spooky = new Spooky({
    child: transport: 'http'
    casper:
      logLevel: 'debug'
      verbose: true
  })
```

and this produces the following error.

Error: spawn casperjs ENOENT

I can't require casperjs or I get this error:

Error: Cannot find module 'casperjs'

Thanks for the help in advanced :).

Comment: Have you installed casperjs?

npm install -g casperjs

Comment: ENOENT is an old unix error that basically translates to 'file not found'. I'd guess @Gary's advice will fix it.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the quick response. Yep, I have installed casperjs using npm install, but I believe that because casperjs isn't a node module I need to do something additional to get it to be seen, however I can't figure out what this additional step might be.